# Laravel 5.2 testing How to follow DRY principle?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing

Everytime I need to test method as authenticated user, I always insert role table because it has relationship with user table, then create new user.

Like this below code.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Role;

class CouponsTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    use DatabaseMigrations;
    //use WithoutMiddleware;

    public function test_index_coupon(){

        //factory(App\Models\Coupon::class, 5)->create()->toArray();  

       DB::table('roles')->insert([
          ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'customer'],
          ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'partner'],
          ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'admin'],
        ]);


       $user = User::create([
           'id' => 3,
           'password' => bcrypt('123456789'),
           'email' => 'admin@domain.co.id',
           'role_id' => '3',
           'status' => 'confirmed',
           'balance' => 0,
        ]);

        $this->actingAs($user)->visit('admin/coupons')->seePageIs('admin/coupons');


    }


    public function test_create_coupon()
    {

        DB::table('roles')->insert([
          ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'customer'],
          ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'partner'],
          ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'admin'],
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
           'id' => 3,
           'full_name' => 'Admin Full Name',
           'password' => bcrypt('123456789'),
           'email' => 'admin@domain.co.id',
           'role_id' => '3',
           'status' => 'confirmed',
           'balance' => 0,
        ]);

        $this->actingAs($user)->visit('admin/coupons/create')->seePageIs('admin/coupons/create');

    }
}
```

I know this is bad practice.

How should my code looks like to follow DRY principle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is common to use `ModelFactory.php` and define factories for your models.

You can also pass arguments to those models.

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    static $password;
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => $password ?: $password = bcrypt('secret'),
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
        'role_id' => factory(App\Role::class)->create()->id,
    ];
});


$factory->define(App\Role::class, function(Faker\Generator $faker){
     return [
         'name' => $faker->name,
     ];
}
```

You can then do the following in your test:

```
$role = factory(App\Role::class)->create(['name' => 'admin']);

$adminUser = factory(App\User::class)->create(['role_id' => $role->id]);
```

Which if needed in many tests can be done once in your tests `setup()` method and define your admin user as protected variable of your test class .

Keep in mind you should probably also `use DatabaseTransactions;` trait in your test class in order to remove any entries created by the commands above at the end of your tests.